# Subscriptions etc with SSRS and SQL Server 2005 Work Group edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, reporting-services

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to schedule the creation of reports and how to allow users to view them in a SQL Server 2005 Work Group environment where scheduling and subscriptions do not appear to be supported.  SQL Server is installed on a separate machine to that running IIS to support multiple production websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest solution you can fill in parameters to reports in the URL and download the report and save it to a location using scheduler application.

Comment: We think we will create a console application that accesses the ReportServer via the URL and persists the reultant file to disk.  That will get us going. Thank you.